# How I can insert values a dataframe to another dataframe

Tags: r

A similar to my data is:

```
dat1<-read.table (text=" ID Rat Garden  Class   Time1   Time2   Time3
1   12  12  0   15  16  20
1   13  0   1   NA  NA  NA      
2   13  11  0   18  12  16
2   9   0   1   NA  NA  NA      
1   6   13  0   17  14  14
1   7   0   2   NA   NA  NA     
2   4   14  0   17  16  12
2   3   0   2   NA  NA  NA      

", header=TRUE)
 
dat2<-read.table (text=" ID Value1  Value2
1   6   7
2   5   4
", header=TRUE)
```

I want to insert  the values of dat2 to dat1 in the Time1 column. In front of numbers 1 and 2 in the class column.
I get the following outcome.

```
ID  Rat Garden  Class   Time1   Time2   Time3
1   12  12  0   15  16  20
1   13  0   1   6       
2   13  11  0   18  12  16
2   9   0   1   5       
1   6   13  0   17  14  14
1   7   0   2   7       
2   4   14  0   17  16  12
2   3   0   2   4
```

Comment: Are those Value colums correspond to Class 1

Comment: Yes, That's correct

Comment: The code to produce dat1 gives an error but If we add fill=TRUE to the read.table statement so that the empty cells in dat1 are NA's and if the rule is to fill in the NA's with the values in dat2, except for the dat2$ID column, column by column then `dat1$Time1[is.na(dat1$Time1)] <- unlist(dat2[-1])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may group by 'ID', and `replace` the 'Time1' where the `NA` values occur with the `unlist`ed 'dat2' 'Value' columns where the `ID` matches

```
library(dplyr)
dat1 %>% 
   group_by(ID) %>%
   mutate(Time1 = replace(Time1, is.na(Time1), 
     unlist(dat2[-1][dat2$ID == cur_group()$ID,]))) %>%
   ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 8 × 7
     ID   Rat Garden Class Time1 Time2 Time3
  <int> <int>  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1     1    12     12     0    15    16    20
2     1    13      0     1     6    NA    NA
3     2    13     11     0    18    12    16
4     2     9      0     1     5    NA    NA
5     1     6     13     0    17    14    14
6     1     7      0     2     7    NA    NA
7     2     4     14     0    17    16    12
8     2     3      0     2     4    NA    NA
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a wild ride:
First we pull the values as a vector from `dat2`.
Then we put alternating an `NA` into the vector until it gets column length of `dat1` and
finally we use `coalesce` after `cbind`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

vector <- dat2 %>% 
  pivot_longer(-ID) %>% 
  arrange(name) %>% 
  pull(value)
      
col_x <- c(sapply(vector, c, rep(NA, 1)))

cbind(dat1, col_x) %>% 
  mutate(col_x = lag(col_x)) %>% 
  mutate(Time1= coalesce(Time1, col_x), .keep="unused")
```

```
 ID Rat Garden Class Time1 Time2 Time3
1  1  12     12     0    15    16    20
2  1  13      0     1     6    NA    NA
3  2  13     11     0    18    12    16
4  2   9      0     1     5    NA    NA
5  1   6     13     0    17    14    14
6  1   7      0     2     7    NA    NA
7  2   4     14     0    17    16    12
8  2   3      0     2     4    NA    NA
```